# Draw a polygon containing many points in google maps

Tags: maps, polygon, points

I have a list of 50+ points within a city, and I need to draw an outline or perimeter containing all of those points. I mean, some point will be inside the perimeter and should not be displayed. I just need to get the points that forms the perimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a [Convex hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).